# Automating a Script with ClearML

Tags: python, clearml

I am using ClearML to automate a script. I'm new to the tool and I haven't found any tutorials for this. The goal I'm trying to accomplish is automate several python scripts so that a server is spun up and torn down as necessary to run them using clearml. Can anyone point me to documentation or explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the ClearML team (formerly Trains)

This depends on the type of scripts you wish to run. If these are devops-like scripts (i.e. no workload or GPU required), you can use the built-in Services Agent running as part of the ClearML Server deployment, enqueuing tasks to the `services` queue as required - these will be picked up by the agent and run locally on the server machine.
As for triggering tasks, take a look at `clearml-task` (documentation [here](https://clear.ml/docs/latest/docs/apps/clearml_task)) which allows you to create a task and enqueue it in a single command.